# jQuery Mobile Page Events Vs rel=external & document.ready for linking pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I link HTML pages in my site with `<a href="quote_product.html?flag=new"  data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="Plus" rel="external" >Add</a>.` 
It works very well, since it doesn't ignore the head element like a regular jQuery mobile link.

I use input `$( document ).ready(function()` in my head element in order to do any changes on a page that I want.

I don't use any jQuery Mobile Page Events or multipages. I find it much easier this way, since it basically uses old school HTML and JS when I transfer info and load pages.

Should I change my site to use Query Mobile Page Events, like pagecreate instead rel=external & document.ready? What are the benefits and disadvantages of both ways? Which way is better and why?

Thanks

Comment: page events give you more control over your site and DOM manipulating. Using `.ready()` isn't a good idea in jQM. Using `rel=external` loads page normally without Ajax and you lose transition effect. __Q:__ why are you using jQM if you aren't using its' features?

Comment: I want to use jQuery mobile design functionality. Why it's not good to use external? It seems to work great.

Comment: There is no harm in using `external`, you just lose animation/transition when moving from page to another.